# Why am I getting "Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()" from valgrind?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am fairly new to programming and am trying to create a program to play the card game crazy eights against a computer opponent. I am getting this error in my function that adds hands from the deck to the players hand. Here is my hand class:

```
class Hand {
  private:
    Card* cards;
    int n_cards;  // Number of cards in the hand.
  public:
  // must have constructors, destructor, accessor methods, and mutator methods
Hand();
~Hand();
Hand(const Hand&);
Hand& operator= (const Hand&);
void set_cards(int n, Card card);
void set_n_cards(const int n_cards);
Card get_cards(int i);
int get_n_cards();
void increase_n_cards();
bool ifPlayable(int cardNum, Card& topPile);
void isEight(Card&);
void playCard(int index);
};
```

and here is the function:

```
void Hand::set_cards(int n, Card card)
{
    Card** temp = &cards;
Card* new_hand = new Card[n_cards+1];

for(int i = 0; i < n_cards; i++)
{
new_hand[i].setCard((*temp)[i].getSuit(),(*temp)[i].getRank());

}

new_hand[n_cards].setCard(card.getSuit(),card.getRank());

delete[] *temp;
*temp = nullptr;
*temp = new_hand;
n_cards++;

}
```

I am very confused as I haven't gotten this type of seg fault before and would love some help. Also, n_cards keeps reverting back to 0 after the function ends. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Using pointers like this is not needed in modern C++ programs.  You have `std::vector` to take care of all of these details of resizing and managing memory.

Comment: I would do that, but unfortunately, we are not allowed to use vectors for this assignment.

Comment: What is the point of the `temp` variable other than to gratuitously complicate your code, making it harder to debug?

Comment: The "n_cards keeps reverting back to 0" symptom is suspicious and suggests we might need a [mre]. Errors in other parts of your code might have been able to hide their effects until this function was called. That is, the place where the error is detected is not necessarily the place where the error occurred.